# forum system for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forum

I need to integrate a forum into my web site, is there any forum system ready to be integrate or it will be better to build a new one from scratch?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/radar/forem will be the greatest but is still in dev

Answer (score 2):

Altered Beast :)

https://github.com/courtenay/altered_beast/

Answer (score 2):

Or if you'd like something less obstrusive

> The goal of Forum Monster, is to provide a simple, and easy to setup forum application without having to dictate how your site it setup.

https://github.com/gitt/forum_monster

Via [Forum solution for Rails 3 and Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158850/forum-solution-for-rails-3-and-devise/6164002#6164002)