# Forum solution for Rails 3 and Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, forum

I'm looking for a forum solution for a website I'm building. I'm using Devise and Rails 3, so does there exist any pluggable solutions?

What about 3rd party services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The goal of Community, is to provide a simple, and easy to setup forum application without having to dictate how your site it setup.

https://github.com/gitt/community

Answer (score 2):

You could build one yourself, you'll be surprised that it's not that time consuming, and you won't have to deal with the bloat that 3rd party solutions might come with. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

[Savage Beast](https://github.com/wbharding/savage-beast), [Altered Beast](https://github.com/courtenay/altered_beast) and [rBoard](https://github.com/radar/rboard/%5d) may be good starting points, but note that they are only for Rails 2.x afaics.

Note: rBoard has a [Rails 3 branch](https://github.com/radar/rboard/tree/rails3) but I have no idea how stable that is.